# Powershell pack uri object

Tags: wpf, xaml, powershell, uri, pack

I'm trying to create a pack ui referencing a xaml resource inside of an assembly file in powershell. After reading this [post](http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2008/04/30/pack-uri-authority---local-assembly--executable.aspx) I tried to do this:

```
$resource = new-object system.uri("pack://application:,,,/WPFResource;component/test.xaml")
```

The I get an error noting that it is expecting a port since there are two colons.

Can anyone please advice?

Comment: good question. I get the same error pasting the examples in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx into C# too

Comment: if you're trying to apply an assembly resource to your window, i think you can add reference to the dll and in the app.xaml create a resource dictionary similar to this: <ResourceDictionary Source="/<assemblyname>;<path_to>/resource.xaml" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go about this one of two ways. One is to load up and init the WPF infrastructure:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework,PresentationCore
[windows.application]::current > $null # Inits the pack protocol
new-object system.uri("pack://application:,,,/WPFResource;component/test.xaml")
```

The other way is to manually register the pack protocol:

```
$opt = [GenericUriParserOptions]::GenericAuthority
$parser = new-object system.GenericUriParser $opt
if (![UriParser]::IsKnownScheme("pack")) { 
    [UriParser]::Register($parser,"pack",-1) 
}
new-object system.uri("pack://application:,,,/WPFResource;component/test.xaml")
```